# File search engine - where to start?

Tags: django, drupal, solr, full-text-search, search-engine

I have to build a simple file search engine for an intranet (a view with a field for searching pdf, txt, etc. and a view for display best matches). I'm searching for a solution/suggestions:

I'm thinking about Django + Solr (haystack), or Drupal. Are there opensource platforms for this goal?

**edit:**

I've chose Django + Haystack solution.
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/rich_content_extraction.html?highlight=pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No platforms aside from building django models in a database of your choice.  installing django-haystack, solr server etc... register your models with haystack, build your UI (really just two pages/3 views)

It should be a relatively simple process in django.

One views.py file for three pages,

index, search (not even a page, just simply a view that returns results, results (template displays database objects returned by the search view).

With Django you could have this done in 45 minutes if you have experience with Django.  Without experience probably several hours, maybe a couple of days if you get hung up.

Comment: I have build a simple example for create/search objects. Next step: indexing/search files. Don't know where to start if not from google ;)

Comment: The django-haystack documents do a decent job explaining how to setup haystack.  I recommend solr since it's the easiest to setup.  You will need to lookup instructions on how to install the solr server for your  particular platform.

Comment: You could even use django's default search capabilities, but it will literally match any search for things like the letter a. Basically this would be a horrible approach for production, but if you're just doing a basic project to display an idea, Java/Solr may be overkill.